# Noticing strange behavior with strings in c

Tags: c, string

Still in learning mode and may be the following question is a really dumb but I dont have any idea why it is happening..

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
    {
      /* code to accept string and then a character from stdin */
         char str[20], inp;
         /*take string from stdin */
         printf("string:\n");
         scanf("%s",str);
         fflush(stdin);
         /*input a character */
         printf("char:\n");
         scanf("%c",&inp);/* code does not reach this point and exits */

    }
```

As mentioned in the comment, after I input the string , for eg. 'strng' the code just exits after printing char: but it does not wait for me input the character. As per my understanding, I have given the size of the array large enough to store the string and if the string entered is smaller than the size of the str array, the compiler will automatically add null character at the end of the string and proceed further. Am I missing something or is there a mistake in my code. Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a space before the `%c` in the second scanf like this:

`scanf(" %c",&inp)`

And as stated by others `fflush` is defined only for output streams.

Comment: Thanks acme.. this did the trick. However now I know that I need to be careful with scanf. Cinicular removed his post but the faqs he pointed were really helpful.

Comment: @Faizan I removed my post and +1 Acme because his answer is more better :-). Terse is good.

Comment: @cnicutar - Your answer had great information for others and that is why i had marked this question as my favorite :) >> Please `undelete` your answer if you can.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing `fflush(stdin);`
 and put a space before %c in `scanf(" %c",&inp);`

Comment: Removed but it does not help. I though may be clearing the input buffer will help so i later added this but it did not help. Removed it again and the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

First of all **[`fflush(stdin)` is wrong](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html)**. Many people recommend it but it is plain and simple undefined.

The problem is caused by `scanf` leaving `\n` in the input buffer because "%s" doesn't read whitespace characters. When `scanf("%c"..)` is reached, it is immediately "satisfied" and fills `inp` with `\n` and calls it a day.

The problem is common enough, see these C FAQs:

- [Scanf interlace](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html)
- [Scanf problems](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

One (possibly dangerous) solution is to discard `\n` input:

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    ;
```

Another solution might be to use `fgets` and parse that, or possibly read one character at a time with `getc`, or maybe tweak the second scamf to discard whitespace characters.