# Having trouble with do while loops in C

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I am a beginner at C and I am writing a basic program that converts dollars to euros. For some reason the program is not running this line: "scanf("%c", &yn);". If I remove the do while loop the program works fine.

Instead of stopping and waiting for the user to enter 'y' or 'n' the loop restarts and asks for the usd amount again.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()

{
    float usd = 0.00;
    float euro = 0.00;
    char yn;
    const float conversion = 0.75;

    do {
        /*get amount to convert*/
        printf("Please enter the amount of USD you want to convert to Euros: ");
        scanf("%f", &usd);

        /*convert amount*/
        euro = (usd * conversion);

        /*output results and ask to continue*/
        printf("\n%.2f USD equals %.2f Euros. Do you want to convert another amount? (y/n): ", usd, euro);
        scanf("%c", &yn);
        printf("\n");


        /*if yes, get new amount to convert. if no, program ends*/
    } while (yn = 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you say "the program is not running this line"? It most cetainly *is* running that line. Perhaps you should print the return value from `scanf`, and the value written into `yn` to determine what is happening. (Hint: `yn` will equal `'\n'`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
do {
  // ...
} while( yn == 'y'); // At this statement you are making an assignment,
                     // not comparison. Use the equal to operator.
```

Comment: That is only the reason for why it loops around and prompts again for USD. The main issue is that the program does not even prompt for 'y' 'n' character input.

Answer (score 4):

Your scanf is picking up the newline from reading the float previously. You need to account for the new line, `scanf(" %c", &yn);` should work.. Even once you enter a 'y' or a 'n' the evaluation will fail because you are assigning `'y'` to `yn` which would always evaluate as true. change it to `while( yn == 'y')`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `yn = 'y'` to `yn == 'y'`. In the first case, you're *setting* yn to `'y'` while what you want to do is *compare* it to `'y'`. The `==` operator is used for comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

You meant to do `==` in your `while` condition, not a single `=`, that will always evaluate truthfully.

Answer (score 1):

Give a space in the second scanf before the `%c` like this `scanf(" %c", &yn);`.

Also go through this question, quite similar to your problem:

[Noticing strange behavior with strings in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619106/noticing-strange-behavior-with-strings-in-c)

Also as pointed out by others:

`while (yn = 'y');` will be (yn **==** 'y')

Answer (score 0):

while (yn = 'y') should be while (yn **==** 'y')

Answer (score 0):

You've proboly noticed, and understood the silly bug, however, this is a very common bug, and it's really hard to trace, because the assignment operation always return the right value of the assignment. There are two ways to minimize the chance for such a bug. the first is to use `#define equals =`.
The other one is two always replace the order of comparisment. so `yn == 'y'` will become `'y' == yn`. In this way, if by mistake replace the == with = you'll get compilation error.
I don't know a single person who haven't stumbbled upon this bug...

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out, the problem is that you've accidentally written an assignment statement instead of the equality test. We've all done that.

But on a side note, as a junior C programmer you may come across advice telling you to switch the order of the operands in an equality test (which will cause a compile error if you make that same mistake), or #define EQUALS (or, on a related topic, TRUE and FALSE). This is very bad advice.

Reversing the order of the operands makes the code harder to read, because you don't actually want to compare the constant to the variable, you want to compare the variable to the constant. (Also, it won't help at all if you are comparing two variables.) Using #defines also clutters up the code with irrelevant nonsense. There is no boolean datatype in C, and C does have similarly named assignment and equality operators.

The better advice is to learn the language, not try to make it look like something it's not.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, and while you're right about #defines, you're wrong about NOT putting the constant to compare on the left. The = vs. == issue is a usability problem in c, and usability problems are real, to some degree at all levels. Even for experts, like you. The habit 'codes around' this 'bug' in the usability of the language. True, it doesn't work for variables, but this is an 'odds' thing and giving yourself better odds at success == usually a very good idea in any corner of life. Pretending you are infallible is not. Especially when you can work around the infallibilities you know

Comment: Well this isn't a debate so I won't rehash my previous, but I will add that this sort of problem is why there are compiler warnings: gcc -Wall will catch 'if (c = 1)' suspects. Then of course we run into the "compiler gives too many warnings so I switch them off" thing, which to me is the equivalent of a doctor saying "the X-ray showed too many broken bones so I ignored it and gave the patient a band-aid." In terms of good coding habits, it is far far better to compile with warnings than to write backwards expressions.

Comment: couldn't agree more about the warnings, well said. Now, on to my legs bending in all the wrong places...